# SQLite error for Android: "Column is not unique"

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have spent lots of time searching for the answer, but I couldn't find it.

I'm trying to use a SQLite database on my Android app, but when I try to add a new object with the `db.insert(object)`, I get an error saying that my Primary Key is not UNIQUE.

What am I doing wrong?

SQLite Database:

```
public class SqlCadastro extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager"; 
    private static final String TABLE_MATERIAS = "Materias";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_NOME = "Nome";
    private static final String KEY_NOTA1 = "Tri1";
    private static final String KEY_NOTA2 = "Tri2";
    private static final String KEY_NOTA3 = "Tri3";
    private static final String KEY_PRENOTA3 = "Est3Tri";
    private static final String KEY_MA = "MA";
    private static final String KEY_PREPFV = "EstPFV";
    private static final String KEY_PFV = "PFV";

    public SqlCadastro(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MATERIAS + "("
                + KEY_NOME + " TEXT UNIQUE," + KEY_NOTA1 + " FLOAT," + KEY_NOTA2 + " FLOAT," + KEY_PRENOTA3 + " FLOAT,"
                + KEY_NOTA3 + " FLOAT," + KEY_MA + " FLOAT," + KEY_PREPFV + " FLOAT, " + KEY_PFV + " FLOAT, PRIMARY KEY (" + KEY_NOME + ") ON CONFLICT IGNORE)" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MATERIAS);
        onCreate(db);
    }


    public void addMateria(Materias materia) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NOME, materia.getNome());
        values.put(KEY_NOTA1, Float.toString(materia.getNota1()));
        values.put(KEY_NOTA2, Float.toString(materia.getNota2()));
        values.put(KEY_PRENOTA3, Float.toString(materia.getPreNota3()));
        values.put(KEY_NOTA3, Float.toString(materia.getNota3()));
        values.put(KEY_MA, Float.toString(materia.getMA()));
        values.put(KEY_PREPFV, Float.toString(materia.getPrePFV()));
        values.put(KEY_PFV, Float.toString(materia.getPFV()));

        // Inserting Row
        db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_MATERIAS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
}
```

The error log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column Nome is not unique (code 19)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native      Method)
     at    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:775)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
    at    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(SQLiteDatabase.java:1365)
    at com.testemedia.mediacp2.SqlCadastro.addMateria(SqlCadastro.java:68)
    at com.testemedia.mediacp2.Cadastrar.onClick(Cadastrar.java:49)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am i doing wrong?

You are adding a row to a database table where your desired primary key is already used by another existing row. Either:

- Use a separate column as the primary key, such as adding `_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`, or
- Make sure that everything you put in the `Nome` column is unique

Comment: Looks like that worked. But now i have to show the list to the user. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The column `Nome` (`KEY_NOME`) is declared unique & as primary key (which implies unique).
Make sure, that there are no duplicate but unique values in `Nome`.